# CSS version of table page layout

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to learn css. up to now I have been lagging behind and using tables to manage my page layout.

I want to migrate to css but am having a few issues aceiving this.

My current page layout using a table:

[image]

I tried to recreate this layout using css as per code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>page layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        html, body {
            text-align:center;
        }

        #wrapper {       
            margin: 0 auto;       
            width: 1200px; 
            text-align:left;}

        #header {
            height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
            background: green;
        }

        #main {
            background: yellow;
            float: left;
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px
        }

        #menu {
            background: red;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px
        }

        #pics {
            background: brown;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px
        }
        #pics {
            background: brown;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px
        }
        #adverts {
            background: pink;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px
        }

        #footer {
            background: grey;
            float: left;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 100px
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    Header
</div>

<div id="menu">
    menu
</div>
<div id="pics">
    pics
</div>
<div id="main">
    main
</div>

<div id="adverts">
    adverts
</div>

<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

As you can see the pics div is in the incorrect place, this should be under the menu div not at the bottom of the page?

My questions, how do I get the pics div in the correct place? and secondly how do I center the entire page?

Lastly, is this the best method of managing my page layout? what will happen in the event that my 'main' div is too full of information? will it autoadjust its height in order to display all the info? is this what the overflow: auto will allow?

Appreciate the help as always,
R

Comment: You need a div to wrap your body (menu, pics, main, adverts). Look into a CSS grid framework http://960.gs/

Comment: you should consider using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pics` div is out of sequence. It needs to appear before the `footer` div:

You have this:

```
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>

<div id="pics">
    pics
</div>
```

You need to have this:

```
<div id="pics">
    pics
</div>

<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

In order to get the `menu` and `pics` divs arranged the way you want, create a `div` that wraps (contains) them both (`menupics` in my CSS/HTML below).

This code works just as you have it laid out above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>page layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width:1200px;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #header {
            height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
            background: green;
        }

        #main {
            background: yellow;
            float: left;
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        #menupics {
          float: left;
          width: 200px;
          height: 400px;
        }

        #menu {
            background: red;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        #pics {
            background: brown;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        #adverts {
            background: pink;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        #footer {
            background: grey;
            float: left;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 100px
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
    Header
</div>

<div id="menupics">
  <div id="menu">
    menu
  </div>
  <div id="pics">
    pics
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
    main
</div>

<div id="adverts">
    adverts
</div>


<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, works perfectly and the penny finally dropped. Thanks as always. Really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> **How do I center the entire page?**

You will want to put a div around you other divs that has a width set and the following css rule: 
`margin: 0 auto 0 auto;`.

> **Is this the best method of managing my page layout?**

You html isn't bad but your CSS specifies too much.  With CSS based layouts less is really more.  Avoid specifying widths and heights where ever possible.

In the section above I mentioned adding a div that wraps your other divs so you could center the page.  That div will need a width assigned to it so it can be centered but for divs inside this wrapper if you don't assign a width then they will automatically fill the available space horizontally as they are a block level elements.  Additionally if a height is not specified it will occupy a height based on the content within it.  So if you want it to automatically get larger you can just not specify a height.  Lastly if you want your divs to occupy some minimum height and not grow larger than some maximum height there is the min-height and max-height css rules (note these rules won't work with some legacy browsers).

I can't address your other questions as my work blocks that image host )=.